# CFWheels - DeObfuscate ID on query paging?

Tags: coldfusion, railo, deobfuscation, cfwheels

I am obfuscating URL's in my app (which is great), but I'd like to disable this for pagination URL's because I'd like the user to be able to enter whatever number they like.

Settings.cfm:

```
<cfset set(obfuscateURLs = true) />
```

Home.cfc (controller):

```
<cffunction name="home">

        <cfparam name="params.page" default="1" />

        <cfset linkList = model("link").findAll(
            select="linkTitle,linkPoints,linkID,linkAuthority,linkCreated,linkUpVoteCount,linkDownVoteCount,linkCommentCount,userName,userID",
            include="user", 
            order="linkPoints DESC",
            handle="linkListPaging",
            page=params.page,
            perPage=5
        ) />

    </cffunction>
```

Home.cfm (view)

```
<ul class="pagination">
            <cfoutput>
                #paginationLinks( 
                    route="paginateLatest", 
                    handle="linkListPaging",
                    page=1,
                    name="page", 
                    windowSize=5, 
                    prependToPage="<li>", 
                    appendToPage="</li>", 
                    classForCurrent="current"
                )#
            </cfoutput>
        </ul>
```

Can I do DeObfuscate on an as needed basis?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 1):

The setting to obfuscate params is an all-or-nothing deal. Just as you can't override this behavior for `linkTo()`, you cannot override it for `paginationLinks()` either.

I would suggest building a plugin as I bet there will be other developers out there who would want this in the future. There may be a way to tell the controller to not obfuscate/deobfuscate a parameter named `page`. You would need to update both how `urlFor()` works as well as how the controller deobfuscates as it handles incoming requests. You may also consider providing a configuration option to use `set()` to "blacklist" a set of `params` keys to never be obfuscated (with `page` being a default).